7-Zip - Is it possible to exclude second level (or beyond) subfolders
Say I want to archive the whole c:\codebase folder, but I want to exclude c:\codebase\laragon\bin, how do I do that?
I've tried the following, but didn't work:
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -xr!laragon\bin "c:\temp\codebase.zip" c:\codebase


If you don't mind powershell, and add one file at a time, you can use get-childitem -depth 2 | foreach-object { 7z a $_ c:\temp\codebase.zip}

Archive c:\codebase, exclude c:\codebase\laragon\bin outfile C:\Temp\codebase.zip

From CMD:

@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\Temp\codebase.zip" "C:\codebase" -xr!"codebase\laragon\bin"


From PowerShell:

& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\Temp\codebase.zip" "C:\codebase" -xr!"codebase\laragon\bin"


-tzip : Type of archive. e.g. -t7z, -trar
another format -xr!"*\laragon\bin"
to exclude all bin folder -xr!"bin"

Thanks, but wouldn't that exclude all "bin" folders, including say c:\codebase\anotherfolder\bin?

-@Nick Maybe I don't understand the question. So your goal is to exclude only the bin folder or everything inside bin, or anything else?

I want to exclude not just any bin folder, but only the laragon\bin folder. I don't want to automatically exclude any other bin folder (eg someotherfolder\bin), and it seems to me "-xr!bin" will indiscriminately exclude all bin folders.

Oh. I understand now. I thought there was only one bin folder. I will update the answer soon. Thank You.
